# Is the social boo theme dead in codenameone?

Tags: themes, codenameone

I've been struggling with app dialog and toolbar appearances in the social boo theme for some time. I recently discovered that my struggles are less with my code and more with the theme. In the GUI Builder switching the Native Themes from IOS6, IOS7, and Android (Gingerbread I believe) all create very different dialogs ranging from matching to illegible to ok. Also I found this demo:

https://www.codenameone.com/demos-SocialBoo.html

and ran it on my Android (S6) phone. The below image illustrates the problems:

[Social Boo visualizations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDBzV.png)

Note the Dialog's appearances as they change in the first 3 images. Please note in the 3rd Android picture I'm clicking on the Cancel button to show how differently it paints with the pointer pressed. The 4th image is again from my phone, note the toolbar button on the top right with a square image placed oddly over a rectangular button. Ah finally, all the problems I'm seeing in my app happening elsewhere!

Hopefully my title question now makes more sense. Is the social boo theme being updated with CodenameOne releases or is it dead? Should I abandon using it as it'll have quite varied appearances on devices especially iOS? I'd love to have the theme maintain the IOS6 appearance on all devices - how can I achieve that goal? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit out of date. Most developers just [cut a PSD design](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/psd-to-app-revisited.html) from scratch which works best when based on a native theme.

You can easily fix these things if you want to work with that theme though. When we implement a theme we don't aim to implement every feature that might be needed as those are hard to predict and will increase the theme size. The original theme didn't include design for dialogs so some behaviors leaked out.

You can use [theme constants](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html) and UIID's like the theme constant `dlgButtonCommandUIID` to determine the UIID of the buttons within the dialog.

Comment: This is only for styling not code. However, if you feel strongly about this you can use the CSS plugin if you prefer using code see http://www.codenameone.com/blog/rounded-corners-shadows-and-gradients-with-css.html and https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-css-to-import-images.html

Comment: Thank you Shai. I have now added in the Designer: Dialog, DialogBody, DialogContentPane, and DialogTitle. I have underived all the style tabs and set everything to look like I want (as in IOS6). I have set includeNativeBool to false (which messed up much of my desired look otherwise but one problem at a time). Now my dialogs look closer to desired however the buttons and text are completely misplaced. The buttons are an inch below the dialog and the title and components a half inch above. I'm clearly missing something, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I deleted the other comment, I never intended it to post. I hit enter thinking new paragraph, then edit, then worked on something else, and then crap there it is posted.

Comment: Can you file a question on that with screenshots and a bit more of a description. Personally, I would not use `includeNativeBool=false`. We don't test it as much and it effectively removes an important layer of abstraction we use on devices so you would be in a position where you will need to dig deep into the code to find some answers (since we don't use that mode I honestly don't remember what might fail in that mode)